# Regex for git branch naming

Tags: regex, git, regex-group

I am looking for a regex to enforce a valid git branch naming convention.

Rules are

1. A branch name can only be `main`, `master`, `development`
2. A branch name can start with `features`, `tests`, `bugfix`, `hotfix`; followed by `/` description, number, `-`, `_` (*or nesting of it but max allowed in upto 2*)
3. A branch name can start with `release/` then version number, and it can have `beta`, `alpha` or `rc` tag with or without number.

Here are the example of few valid name

```
main
bugfix/user-list
bugfix/user_list
bugfix/123
bugfix/123/account-update
bugfix/123/account_update
bugfix/User_crud/account-update
bugfix/User_crud/account_update
tests/api
tests/123
tests/123/hello
release/1.0.1
release/1.0.1-beta1
release/1.0.1-beta
release/1.0.1-rc3
```

I had written this regex (https://regex101.com/r/n0CAuM/1), but it is not matching all the above example

`^(development|master|main|(((features|tests|bugfix|hotfix)\/(([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)|((\/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+)))|release\/(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\d+)?(-(alpha|beta|rc)[0-9]))))`

Also note as I will be using the regex in a bash script which only support **POSIX regex engine**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the alternations for all 3 parts in their own part of the pattern.

For the groupings, instead of a non capture group you can use a capture group, and for the digits use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

If there is maximum of 1-2 parts, you can use a quantifier `{1,2}`

You could write the pattern as:

```
^(main|development|master|(features|tests|(bug|hot)fix)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*){1,2}|release\/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*(-(alpha|beta|rc)[0-9]*)?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Start outer grouping to match 1 of the 3 allowed patterns

  - `main|development|master` Match 1 of the single named alternatives
  - `|` Or
  - `(features|tests|(bug|hot)fix)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*){1,2}` Match a variation for features, tests and fixes a following with `/` and not starting with `-` or `_` and repeat that part 1 or 2 times
  - `|` Or
  - `release\/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*(-(alpha|beta|rc)[0-9]*)?` Match a variation for the release branch with optional alpha, beta or rc
- `)` Close outer grouping
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q6Jt8G/1) and a [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##dVJNU4MwED3Lr8gwPSTVlLae1OmoP0BvXqTIbGGRzABhktBRm/rXEbBF0JpL3r63m/3KBnRa16AUvK9ojFvMZJljYUgOoiCb6jURb16lUfFMaDMkwiGxWF4OoAdRJKvC8KqMweAJJRwrT@17karifyL/6Md4g9poD0pxQG0dPfJSzDJJFGYIGr3FbD5bjC2@QQOnuF@Uivr2jjc/grBnCsj7isOhwb2xxX9g2GfadqmY4yRSEUGa6buTXbcY/y7Yu04snTOREN9veOGS1Sd5oe2S7GBrNgdtUFmaIJhKobbdMCxt8tlUGtYkZXTt@cA/7vnznF8F59TnYTAk2JTtFhfLvT1U1rh/O65n/sGBcgpZmYJtZ2VVxDphym7ZhATBDTEpFg7pDkapJO4DmCi9bitvaMw0jtRH2Xy3gUMimm4LrOsv).

Example

```
array=(development main bugfix/user-list bugfix/user_list bugfix/123 bugfix/123/account-update bugfix/123/account_update bugfix/User_crud/account-update bugfix/User_crud/account_update tests/api tests/123 tests/123/hello release/1.0.1 release/1.0.1-beta1 release/1.0.1-beta release/1.0.1-rc3 bugfix/ bugfix/- bugfix/_ bugfix/-name bugfix/_name bugfix/-/name bugfix/-/- bugfix/-/_ release/v1.0.1)

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$i" =~ ^(main|development|master|(features|tests|(bug|hot)fix)(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*){1,2}|release/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*(-(alpha|beta|rc)[0-9]*)?)$ ]]; then
      echo "Match: "$i
  else
      echo "No match: "$i
  fi
done
```

Output

```
Match: development
Match: main
Match: bugfix/user-list
Match: bugfix/user_list
Match: bugfix/123
Match: bugfix/123/account-update
Match: bugfix/123/account_update
Match: bugfix/User_crud/account-update
Match: bugfix/User_crud/account_update
Match: tests/api
Match: tests/123
Match: tests/123/hello
Match: release/1.0.1
Match: release/1.0.1-beta1
Match: release/1.0.1-beta
Match: release/1.0.1-rc3
No match: bugfix/
No match: bugfix/-
No match: bugfix/_
No match: bugfix/-name
No match: bugfix/_name
No match: bugfix/-/name
No match: bugfix/-/-
No match: bugfix/-/_
No match: release/v1.0.1
```

Comment: Awesome. I was struggling with it and you made it like a cake walk. Thank you :)